# In what conditions do MC-Dropout-based uncertainties fail to be expressive?

Tags: neural-networks, uncertainty, dropout

I trained a neural network with dropout regularization and computed uncertainty scores for predictions on a test set. However, I found that these uncertainties exhibit a very weak correlation (Pearson: 0.03, Spearman: 0.01) with the model's error, rendering them ineffective.

**Under which conditions do MC-Dropout-based uncertainties fail to adequately capture model uncertainty?**

[image]